# How to make a modal fixed on bootstrap when press a button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a modal in bootstrap and I want when I pressed a button such as Activate or desactivate the image change but the modal still fixed.My problem is when I clicked the button the modal disappears.

```
    <h2>Led1</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" id="led1" align="center">login</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="model_led1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
        <div class="modal-header" style="padding:35px 50px;">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span> Settings</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" style="padding:40px 50px;">
          <form role="form">

            <img src="style/led.png" id="led_on"/>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block" id="led1_activ"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span> Activate</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block" id="led1_desactiv"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span> Desactivate</button>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Cancel</button>

        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
</div>
```

the script of modal's show:

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#led1").click(function(){
        $("#model_led1").modal({
    backdrop: 'static',
        keyboard: false});
    });
});
</script>
```

the script when I cliked on button activate or desactivate:

```
<script>
$("#led1_activ").click(function(){
    socket.emit('state',"led1 is ON");
  var x=document.getElementById("led");
  x.setAttribute("src", "style/led_on.png");

});
$("#led1_desactiv").click(function(){
    socket.emit('state',"led1 is OFF");
    var x=document.getElementById("led");
    x.setAttribute("src", "style/led_off.png");
});

</script>
```

Comment: Try taking out `type = "submit"` in both buttons since you already have `.click` functions controlling the actions.

Comment: I made a JSFiddle for you can you edit it to make it usable for your scenario? so I can see what your problem is? https://jsfiddle.net/trapline/cf2skb76/

Comment: @Trapline I think you have to load bootstrap in that JSFiddle.

Comment: I added resources but that didnt help https://jsfiddle.net/trapline/cf2skb76/2/

Answer (score 0):

`type = "submit"` in Bootstrap will close the modal when it is in any button the modal. In your case you can just take it out in both of your activation and deactivation buttons as these are not needed because you have declared `.click` actions in your `<script></script>`

Comment: I tried it by deleting "type=submit" but when I clicked on Activate the modal disappered.

Answer (score 0):

I put `type=button` and it works.